# jQuery - get element inside parent div's friend div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="input-page">...</div>
  <!-- field 1 -->
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">...</div>
  <!-- field 2 -->
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">...</div>
  <!-- field 3 -->
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding"> <!-- I want to grab this block -->
    <div class="x_panel">
      <div class="x_content">
        <form class="data-table">
          <div class="row">...</div>
          <div class="row">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button>Add</button> <!-- when I click this button -->
      <button>Other</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code is a simplified version, but with the actual code it looks like this:
[image]

Each "`field`" is a combination of the content `div` and the buttons `div`. When I press that Add button, I want to grab the content div that is right above it.

I was thinking about first trying `$(this).closest('.container-fluid')`, and then navigate to the div that is right above the div that has the button I clicked. But I don't know how. Any ideas?

Comment: are you missing some `</div>`s by any chance?

Comment: You have form inputs. You don't get the data from the div, you get it from the inputs. You can assign the inputs individual id or name attributes and use regular css selector queries to get the values.

Comment: Please include the JavaScript code you've tried in the snippet so people don't have to do all of the work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One crude way would be to get the parent/parent's closest sibling with `prev`

```js
$("#AddButton").click(function() {
  var blockToGrab = $(this).parent().parent().prev();  
  // do stuff with block
  console.log("I found: " + blockToGrab.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="input-page">...</div>
  <!-- field 1 -->
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">...</div>
  <!-- field 2 -->
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">...</div>
  <!-- field 3 -->
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding"> <!-- I want to grab this block -->
    <div class="x_panel">
      <div class="x_content">
        <form class="data-table">
          <div class="row">...</div>
          <div class="row">...</div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button id="AddButton">Add</button> <!-- when I click this button -->
      <button>Other</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```